# Do the fields exist without electric charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, maxwell-equations

I read in an old book on electrodynamics by Pauli that

> *theoretically there does not exist any need of charges to be there. Fields can even exist without the charges but still independent fields have not been observed still. EMWs are also produced from any accelerated charges.*

I want to know that have physicists found fields without electric charges today? I also want to know that if there actually does not exist any field without directly or indirectly originated from charges then there is something missing in the Maxwell equations or it is not like that?
I think that until we can experimentally prove the existence of the fields without charges we cannot tell the Maxwell equations a complete theory of the electrodynamics because it allows the fields without charges but if there exist some nature of the electromagnetic entity that it requires charges for fields then it is not explained in these equations.

Comment: is that an actual quote or are you paraphrasing? in any case, which book?

Comment: You'll have to define "field without charges". A quantum (matter) field, for example, rarely originates from a "charge" in any sense. You can also consider EM waves, which need charges to originate from, but are perfectly content travelling through the charge-free vacuum

Comment: @innisfree These are not the exact words but the meaning is not more or less...Exactly the same it is.Book was Lectures On Electrodynamics By Pauli

Comment: @ACuriousMind: That's probably what Pauli had in mind.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have already mentioned that EMWs are also originated from charge so these are not independent of charges.Don't know much about quantum mechanics so can't say anything about that one.

Comment: Gamma rays are emitted also by nuclei, and there, the field is nuclear, the coulombian repulsion is negligible. Besides that, there exists a particle which, so I believe, has nothing to do with electrical charges - the neutrino, and it has an antiparticle. From practical point of view, to think of neutrino-antineutrino annihilation is ridiculous, the neutrino has a negligible cross section for interactions, however, theoretically, its annihilation is possible. But, again QFT is not my domain.

Answer (score 4):

A propagating EM wave is a field that needs no charges. Likewise, a propagating gravitational wave is a field that needs no masses.

However in both cases there is no way (classically) to create the wave without a charge/mass. Considering EM, the divergence of the field is zero unless there is a charge, or put another way since field lines can only begin and end on charges all field lines would have to be infinitely long or looped.

Comment: Please see what I found in Wikipedia: The π^0 meson ... It decays in an electromagnetic force process. The main decay mode, ... is into two photons:

π^0 → 2 γ.

But these words "decays in an electromagnetic force process", do they mean that electric charges are implied? (Maybe in some Feynman diagram?)

Comment: @Sofia: the $\pi_0$ is not an elementary particle. It consists of a pair of charged quarks - either $u\bar{u}$ or $d\bar{d}$. It decays to photons because the **charged** quarks annihilate each other. I suspect you will find in all apparently neutral particles that decay to photons charged particles will be involved somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know cases in which the e.m. field can be produced without charges, however I can tell you how to produce an e.m. field **without electric charges**. Take a neutral particle, meet it with its antiparticle, have them clash, and you'll get gamma rays. The latter are electromagnetic.

Also, gamma emission from excited nuclei, has not much to do with the fact that the nuclei contain protons. The gamma radioactivity originates in eliminating the excess of energy by excited nuclei (where the nuclear field dominates).

If we can say or not that gamma emission from nuclei is without charges, I am not sure. But, in the case of annihilation the charges for generating e.m. field are charges of another field.

(A good question would be here, are a particle and antiparticle opposite charges of some field? For the gravitational field, they are just masses.)

Good luck !

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I can't think of a particle-antiparticle annihilation producing photons that doesn't involve charge somewhere in the process.

Comment: I'm with @John here. The only fundamental neutral fermion is the neutrino and $\nu + \bar\nu$ goes only to $Z^0$ which does not couple directly to photons.