# Physical properties of a field that is both solenoidal and irrotational

Tags: electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I'm studying an electrodynamics course right now and i know the conditions required for a field to be both solenoidal and irrotational at the same time, but I can find a example of any such field.

Comment: Since you know the conditions already, all you need is an electric field to satisfy the irrotational property or a magnetic field to satisfy the solenoidal property. That would be a physical example. For a general one, you could define said vector field using the conditions by construction.

Comment: Maybe look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688152/under-what-condition-is-an-electrostatic-field-both-solenoidal-and-irrotational

Answer (score 0):

Any vector field with $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v} = 0$ satisfies $\vec{v} = \vec{\nabla} f$ for some scalar function $f$; and if the vector field is also solenoidal this implies that $\nabla^2 f = 0$.  Thus, any vector field that is both irrotational and solenoidal can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar field $f$ that satisfies Laplace's equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} +   
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} =0.
$$
It is not too hard to find such a scalar functions (though not every scalar functions satisfies Laplace's equation.)  Some examples:
\begin{align*}
f &= x &\Rightarrow && \vec{v} &= \hat{x} \\
f &= y^2 - z^2 &\Rightarrow && \vec{v} &= y \hat{y} - z \hat{z} \\
f &= - \frac{1}{r} &\Rightarrow && \vec{v} &= \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2} \\
\end{align*}